# Merge two unequal length data frames by factor matching

Tags: manifest-merging

I'm new to R and I have been searching all over to look for a solution to merge two data frames and match them by factor. Some of the data does have white space. Here is a simple example in what I am trying to do:

> df1 = data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), item=c("apple", " ", "coffee", "orange", "bread"))
>
> df2 = data.frame(item=c("orange", "carrot", "peas", "coffee", "cheese", "apple", "bacon"),count=c(2,5,13,4,11,9,3))

When I use the merge() function to combine df1 into df1 by matching by 'item' name, I end up with a "item" column of NAs.

> ndf = merge(df1, df2, by="item")

How do I resolve this issue? Am I getting this because I have white space in my data? Any help would be great. Thanks,